# When i built my custom pallet i got this error

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, rust, substrate-front-end, cargo

[image: this i my code when i compile this code im getting the error as shown in the image can anyone help me fix this im new to substrate and rust]#!

[cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

// Re-export pallet items so that they can be accessed from the crate namespace.
pub use pallet::*;

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
use codec::alloc::string::String;
use frame_system::pallet;
use crate::Config as OtherConfig;

#[pallet::pallet]
#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
pub struct Pallet(_);

#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
type RuntimeEvent: From<Event> + IsType<::RuntimeEvent>;
type AccountId: Parameter + Member + Default + MaybeSerializeDeserialize + frame_system::Config;
}

```
 pub type OfferId = u64;
```

#[pallet::event]
#[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
pub enum Event<T: Config> {
OfferCreated(::AccountId, OfferId),
}

#[pallet::error]
pub enum Error {
InvalidAgeRange,
InvalidCountryCodeLength,
InvalidGender,
InvalidDiabetesCondition,
}

// Define the Offer struct representing an offer
pub struct Offer<T: frame_system::Config + pallet::Config>
where
::AccountId: frame_system::Config,
{
id: OfferId,
country_code: String,
min_age: u8,
max_age: u8,
gender: Gender,
has_diabetes: Option,
creator: ::AccountId,
}

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn offers)]

pub type Offers<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat,OfferId,Offer<T::AccountId>,ValueQuery>;

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn offer_count)]
pub type OfferCount<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, OfferId>;

pub enum Gender{
Male,
Female,
}

pub struct DiabetesCondition {
min_value: u32,
max_value: u32,
}

#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config> Pallet {
#[pallet::weight(0)]
pub fn create_offer( origin: OriginFor,country_code: String,min_age: u8,max_age: u8,gender: Gender,has_diabetes: Option,) -> DispatchResult{
let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

```
                                              // Check age range validity
                                             ensure!( min_age <= max_age && max_age <= 100,Error::<T>::InvalidAgeRange,);

                                             // Check if the country code is valid
                                              ensure!(country_code.len() == 2, Error::<T>::InvalidCountryCodeLength,);

                                               // Check gender validity
                                                match gender {
                                                             Gender::Male | Gender::Female => (), _ => return Err(Error::<T>::InvalidGender.into()),
                                                }

                                                // Check for diabetes condition
                                                   if let Some(diabetes_condition) = has_diabetes {
                                                         ensure!(diabetes_condition.min_value >= 100 && diabetes_condition.max_value <= 200,Error::<T>::InvalidDiabetesCondition,);
                                                           }
```

// Create a new offer
let offer_id = Self::offer_count()?;
let new_offer = Offer {
id: offer_id,
country_code,
min_age,
max_age,
gender,
has_diabetes,
creator: sender.clone(),
};

```
                     Offers::<T>::insert(offer_id, new_offer);
                     OfferCount::<T>::put(offer_id + 1);

                     Self::deposit_event(Event::OfferCreated(sender, offer_id));
                     Ok(())
}
```

}
}

[image: im getting this error error[E0221]: ambiguous associated type AccountId in bounds of T --> /home/ubuntu/substrate-pallets/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:59:76 | 21 | type AccountId: Parameter + Member + Default + MaybeSerializeDeserialize + frame_system::Config; | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ambiguous AccountId from pallet::Config ... 59 | pub type Offers<T: Config> = StorageMap<, Blake2_128Concat,OfferId,Offer<T::AccountId>,ValueQuery>; | ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type AccountId | = note: associated type T could derive from frame_system::Config help: use fully qualified syntax to disambiguate | 59 | pub type Offers<T: Config> = StorageMap<, Blake2_128Concat,OfferId,Offer<::AccountId>,ValueQuery>;]

Comment: Cannot really read your post but try to replace `T::AccountId` with `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId` in the `StorageMap` definition.